# C++ type conversion according to different input types (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm building a function which involves looping to each pixel in the input image.

I want to use pointers to access each value since it's faster to do it.

However, since input image could have different depths (8bits,16bits,32bits), I need to create the correct type of pointer accordingly in order to access the pixel values.

Here's what I do: //src is a cv::Mat type input from OpenCV

```
uchar *pointer = src.ptr<uchar>(0);
if (src.depth() == 1) { (char)*pointer; *pointer = src.ptr<char>(0); }
if (src.depth() == 2) { (ushort)*pointer; *pointer = src.ptr<ushort>(0); }
if (src.depth() == 3) { (short)*pointer; *pointer = src.ptr<short>(0); }
if (src.depth() == 4) { (int)*pointer; *pointer = src.ptr<int>(0); }
if (src.depth() == 5) { (float)*pointer; *pointer = src.ptr<float>(0); }
```

It gives me the error: **a value of type 'char/ushort/short/int/float' can't not be assign to entity of of type 'uchar'**

If there any way I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use 1,2,3... , but `CV_8U`, `CV_16U`, `CV_16S`, `CV_32S`, `CV_32F` respectively. Also you can't cast a `pointer` like that

Comment: @Miki Thank you for pointing it out, I though they are the same since OpenCV define those them with numbers.  Do you have any workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave no information about this src structure, I can't really figure out what your goal is.

It seems like bad design in sense of structure and relationship between objects since you can't just simply change the type of a value.

What you could actually do (if that helps) is specializing the structure of your src variable like this:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int depth>
struct Image;

template <typename T>
struct Image<0> {}; // Implement with char*

template <typename T>
struct Image<1> {}; // Implement with unsigned char*

template <typename T>
struct Image<2> {}; // Implement with short*

// and so on...
```

This will make an own struct for each depth and is even faster since you don't have to do runtime conditions.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a good method and I will look into that. Sorry forgot to mention the input type.  It's a cv::Mat type input for images from OpenCV